# Mod Rewrite 500 Error Correction

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file that is using Mod_Rewrite but I am running into a problem if someone puts in junk in the URL it generates a 500 error, and displays all my mod information.  I would like to either stop it from generating the 500 error or forward that error to a different page.  I have tried.

```
 Error Document 500 /index.php
```

...but it does not work or redirect.

Here is my full .htaccess

```
 Options -Indexes
 Options +FollowSymlinks

 ErrorDocument 500 /index.php

 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^BEARS bears.php?page=bears [NC,L]

 RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.domian.org/login.php [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domian.org/login.php [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domian.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domian.org/$1 [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domian.org [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domian.org/$1 [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.domian.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domian.org/$1 [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)/DB/(.+)/page/(.+)$ $1.php?DB=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)/DB/(.+)$ $1.php?DB=$2 [L,QSA]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ $1.php?page=$2 [L,QSA]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also does anyone know where the 500 error is being generated from.  I know the error folder has the error documents in there, but this error says "Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request" , and I cannot find where this is pulling from.

```
[Thu Sep 22 11:11:40 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 74.84.118.99] redirected from r->uri = /test.html.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
[Thu Sep 22 11:11:40 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 74.84.118.99] redirected from r->uri = /test.html.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
[Thu Sep 22 11:11:40 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 74.84.118.99] redirected from r->uri = /test.html.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
[Thu Sep 22 11:11:40 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 74.84.118.99] redirected from r->uri = /test.html.php.php.php.php.php.php
[Thu Sep 22 11:11:40 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 74.84.118.99] redirected from r->uri = /test.html.php.php.php.php.php
[Thu Sep 22 11:11:40 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 74.84.118.99] redirected from r->uri = /test.html.php.php.php.php
[Thu Sep 22 11:11:40 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 74.84.118.99] redirected from r->uri = /test.html.php.php.php
[Thu Sep 22 11:11:40 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 74.84.118.99] redirected from r->uri = /test.html.php.php
[Thu Sep 22 11:11:40 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 74.84.118.99] redirected from r->uri = /test.html.php
[Thu Sep 22 11:11:40 2011] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 74.84.118.99] redirected from r->uri = /test.html
```

Where is this loop happening?  Not seeing it.

Comment: Look at the server's error log - it'll have much more detail about the cause of the error. What you get in the browser is by design very vague, as 500 error details can leak server/code information that should not be made public.

Comment: [Thu Sep 22 10:44:42 2011] [error] [client 74.84.118.99] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://www.streatoronized.org/  - - Htaccess must be causing a lot of redirects when garbage is put in it.

Comment: so... if someone enters a junk url, your rewrites got into an infinite-ish loop. You'll have to add something to handle a bogus url case to prevent this.

Comment: I just put my log into debug mode and I'm getting .php appended on to the garbage several times.  I'm not sure where my .htaccess is causing this. (See above)

Comment: Obvious method: start commenting out the individual chunks of the .htaccess and see if/when things change.

Comment: Looks like it was the last Rewrite.  The good news is it doesn't even look like I need that rule.  Thanks for help in resolving this, seems as if my brain has turned to mush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on your answer, it is more specifically this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

which does not check to see if the filename already ends with PHP.

It loops around, adding `.php.php.php.php` until the max is reached (check `apache/logs/error.log`) and then just serves the original page, which happens to be present, so it looks like everything's ok.

To fix this, add something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ - [L]
```

which stops (`[L]`) if the address ends with `.php`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured I would put the problem solution here just in case someone comes across the same issue.

My problem code was this snippet...

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Seems that a junk entry will cause this too loop like crazy.