# Custom 500 Error page Linux Shared Hosting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, shared-hosting

#### How can I show a custom page when a 500 Internal Server Error occurs?

I created a page called '500.php'.
Then added the following line to my '.htaccess' file to handle the error:

`ErrorDocument 500 /500.php`

And the following line to test/trigger a 500 error:

`e`

But the default 500 page shows up - not my custom one.

I tried editing the first line to this (whole URL):

`ErrorDocument 500 http://danispringer.com/500.php`

But then I get the "Too many redirects" error.

How can I do this?

> - See full htaccess file: [here](https://github.com/DaniSpringer/website/blob/master/htaccess)
> - Related:
>     [Mod Rewrite 500 Error Correction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517470/mod-rewrite-500-error-correction?rq=1) (Doesn't answer - uses rewrite - not ErrorDocument)
>     [Trigger 500 Internal Server Error in PHP and display Apache error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687390/trigger-500-internal-server-error-in-php-and-display-apache-error-page?rq=1) (explains how to trigger - not handle - the error)
>     [Custom error page failed to load after editing htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171766/custom-error-page-failed-to-load-after-editing-htaccess?rq=1) (Doesn't answer - uses rewrite - not ErrorDocument)
>     [Default Error Page PHP 500 errors in Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992387/default-error-page-php-500-errors-in-apache?rq=1) (Dupe of above with no answers)
>     [error file .htacess 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744860/error-file-htacess-500-internal-server-error?rq=1) (Doesn't answer - uses rewrite - not ErrorDocument)

Comment: You don't need to use a RewriteRule if you're going to use ErrorDocument.

Comment: `ErrorDocument 500 /500.php` is enough.

Comment: there's no need to "trigger" an error per se. If and when a script errors out as a server error. Apache takes over and looks for the ErrorDocument 500 automatically.

Comment: that is exactly it ;-) the only way to test it would be with a conditional statement of something that doesn't work, and with something that does. All Apache directives that can be caught, will be triggered and handled respectively of the handle request.

Comment: set your server settings to not show errors but log them and then deliberately leave out a missing semi-colon somewhere; that will trigger a server error. Best I can add to all this and we've just triggered the *"Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"*. The question could get closed and/or trigger a "too chatty, moved to chat...." by a mod. You'll need to let all that sink in and try something ;-) cheers. I believe I answered it somewhat.

Comment: welcome but that answer below, is basically what I wrote up here. I figured you'd of invited me to move my comments to the answers area. I can't delete my comments, I feel I answered the question but if you think I didn't, then you need to tell me. At this point, I don't know what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would not use a php file if not absolutely necessary, because if you have a problem with php that you also can't show your `500.php` page.

I would create a folder `/errors` and put all my error files in this e.g.:

```
/errors/404.html
/errors/403.html
/errors/500.html
```

Now If you looking for a solution to test a 500 error then just create a folder (e.g. `test500folder`) and put an invalid .htaccess  file in this folder `/test500folder/.htaccess`:

`abc`

Now you can test you 500 error if you open `example.com/test500folder/`

but remove: `RewriteRule ^ - [R=500]` and everything else but use only

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html
```

in your main htaccess file to test.

#### Edit:

So I assume that you, or your provider, have configured a location for all you ErrorDocumentes, but these files are deleted now. You have to replace exact this files or configure some other in your providers back end, if possible.

Comment: I added two lines to the empty htaccess I made for the 500folder/. One line has `e` to trigger an error, the second has `ErrorDocument 500 /folder500/500.html` . Makes sense? What URL should I visit?

Comment: Please see updated GitHub: https://github.com/DaniSpringer/website (unfortunately I still see the default error page when visiting /folder500)

Comment: It is! I named it without a dot only in GitHub so you can see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156962/discussion-between-webdesigner-and-dani).

Comment: A .htaccess will only apply to one site, and not the entire server. Just as you don't want to use php file to report server errors, neither do you want a single site responsible for reporting server errors, since the problem may be with the site's configuration.